# SIGABRT Error at App Delegate during runtime

Tags: iphone, swift

I am getting the following error

> **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

The problem comes when I press the Unbutton on the main storyboard. It does not "show segue" as directed.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication,    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
}
```

My Home storyboard class is:

```
import UIKit

class Home: UITableViewController {

var array = ["item1, item2", "item3"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell")
    as! TableviewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.item]
    cell.Title = cell.textLabel?.text!
    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "datasegue"){
        let cell = sender as! TableviewCell
        let detailview = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        detailview.PreTitile = cell.Title
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is not related to `AppDelegate`. Set the exception breakpoint. There is at least one issue: In a table view it's `indexPath.row`, `indexPath.item` is for a collection view

Comment: No improvement, I am still getting the same error here...

Comment: The type of the `sender` in `prepareForSegue` depends on the connection of the segue. The cell is returned only if the segue is connected to the table view cell (rather than to the view controller instance). That could be also the reason.

Comment: I don't think the problem is that the signal between the simulator and the code has been abrupted. Checked all my code connections with the UI elements.

Comment: The error occurs most likely in this line: `let cell = sender as! TableviewCell`. The type of the sender might not be `TableviewCell`. See my latest comment.

Comment: yes i tried that... but its' getting an undeclared type if i use the cell identifier... i have described the cell identifier in the attributes inspector though... and Normally sender is casted as what...??

Comment: There is no `normally`. Once again, it depends on the connection of the segue.

Comment: import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var PreTitile:String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.title = PreTitile
        
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
This is my DetailViewController

Comment: You don't understand. In Interface Builder connect the segue from the **table view cell**, not from the **view controller** to the destination controller.

Comment: Can you set a exception breakpoint with an action of *po $arg1* and copy here the output?